# Want to perform calculation and do group by on a field in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a table A. **Select Field1,field2 from A** , I want to perform a `group by` on `count(field1)` and `group by field 2`. But the count will be a calculation of certain condition on same table like

```
Select (Count(All records) - count(Records which are Rejected)/Count(All records))*100 as [Rate] from A
Group by Field1,field2
```

Result should be

```
Field1 Count
A1      (calculation mentioned above)
B1      (calculation mentioned above)
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: No tried both. it dint help.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this uses `AVG()` with a conditional expression:

```
select field1,
       avg(case when status = 'Rejected' then 0.0 else 100.0 end) as Rate
from A
group by Field1;
```

The first condition is however you decide that a row is rejected.  Also, note that `field1` goes in the `group by` clause if that is what you want in the unaggregated column.

Comment: It dint help. I am trying to get the Participation Rate information from the same table. where the condition is (Count(All records) - count(Records which are Rejected)/Count(All records))*100 and Group it by Department coloumn. Basically I want to know the Participation rate % of all the departments

Comment: If you want an answer that represents the data you are using, then you need to provide a question with the proper field names and data.

Comment: For example , There is one table will 100 rows, 20 of the are Rejected. rest 80 are Not. Those 100 Rows belong to different departments. I want participation rate grouped by department. calculation for participation rate is (100-20)/100 %. The result should be Dep1 10%, dep2 20% ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
Select 
  Field1, 
  sum(case when status = 'R' then 0 else 1 end) / sum(1)*100.0 as [Rate] 
from A
Group by 
  Field1
```

This will calculate the percentage of rows that don't have 'R' as status for each value of Field1.

Edit: To calculate the percentages with the number of the rows from whole table you can use a variable:

```
declare @rows int

select @rows = count(*) from A 

Select 
  Field1, 
  (@rows - sum(case when status = 'R' then 1 else 0 end)) / @rows*100.0 as [Rate] 
from A
Group by 
  Field1
```

Comment: It dint help. I am trying to get the Participation Rate information from the same table. where the condition is (Count(All records) - count(Records which are Rejected)/Count(All records))*100 and Group it by Department coloumn. Basically I want to know the Participation rate % of all the departments

Comment: Does 'all records' mean total records for the table? Then use variable outside the query and fetch the count into that.

Comment: Can you show me a example how to do it. It will be helpfull Tx.

Comment: @user6054582 Now there's an example with total number of rows